In Quarkus(Smallrye messaging), is the worker pool size of a @Blocking consumer tied to the consumer group/partition count of a Kafka topic?
If we have a Kafka topic setup with 8 partitions and we have a @Blocking(value="my-pool", order="false) consumer, provided the system has the resources, can we set the worker pool to 16 for example?
Will that create group of 16 consumers of which only half will be used or the workers/threads in the pool are completely unrelated to the consumer group thus we can have more workers processing as fast as the consumer group can give it to the workers?
Edit:
The Smallrye partitions setting for that specific topic is not set. So I'm guessing this creates a single consumer to read the 8 partitions. Which means that the workers aren't tied to the consumer group, which means we should be able to tune both the consumer group count and the worker pool size for maximum performance?
